# Get QObject Which Called Slot

Tags: qt

I need a way to find out which widget was responsible for calling a slot via a signal. This is assuming that I have multiple widget's signals connected to the same slot within my application.

QSignalMapper seems like a valid answer, but I can't figure out how to get the object that triggered the signal to be passed into my slot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From within any slot handler, [`QObject::sender()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) will return a pointer to the object that sent the signal.